Infinite while loop C
I have this code that is meant to read a file and compare the characters until it matches a word but it's stuck in an infinite loop, this is my code
int main() {
    FILE *file_content;     
    file_content = fopen("fwif.txt", "r");

    if (file_content == NULL) {
        printf("Memory allocation failed");
        return 1;
    }  

    char actual_word[10] = "sylvestric";
    int word_counter = 0;
    char character;
    int line_number;
    int word_size = 10;

    printf("Reading file for word....\n");
    while(( character = getchar()) != EOF) {
       if (putchar(character) == '\n') {
            line_number ++;
       } else {
            if (actual_word[word_counter] == character) {
                word_counter ++;
            } else {
                word_counter = 0;
            }
       }
        if (word_counter == word_size) {
            printf("Word found on line: %d\n", line_number);
            return 0;   
       }
    }
    free(file_content); 
}


Please don't tag C++ on C questions, these are two completely different languages.

char actual_word[10] = "sylvestric"; -- You are forgetting the trailing NULL in the count.

i don't understand @PaulMcKenzie

@Somto -- How many characters are there in the string literal "sylvestric" (the answer is not 10).

if it's not 10 what is it? @PaulMcKenzie

@PaulMcKenzie There is no need for this string to be null terminated. This is not the issue of this code.

@Yksisarvinen -- I understand that.  But admittedly the OP is not aware that the string literal has 11 characters, as they are ignoring the NULL character.

Please note that getchar returns an int. This is actually very important for that comparison against EOF.

char character; while(( character = getchar()) != EOF) Whether this appears to work could depend on the platform, but it is wrong. You need: int character;

@Someprogrammerdude I read somewhere that the value for EOF is an int so the comparison is valid

@Somto -- The string consists of s, y, l, v, e, s, t, r , i, c, \0.  That is 11 characters.  String literals include the terminating null character.

@AviBerger if i change char character to int character does it not affect the comparison of
if (actual_word[word_counter] == character) { word_counter ++;}

@Somto No, because you compare it with the char variable character. When the compiler promotes character to an int, it will do sign-extensikon. So if char is signed, then the char value -1 becomes the int value -1. However, if char is unsigned (which it can be!) then the value of character isn't -1 but 255. Which then gets promoted to the int value 255. Which is not equal to -1 (the typical value of EOF).

thank you very much @PaulMcKenzie for the explanation but is that the cause of the infinite loop issue?
regardless, even if it the word is not found it should iterate through the characters of the file and break out, shouldn't it?

@Somto Half right. "EOF is an int" is correct. "the comparison is valid" is correct, but may not be the comparison you want or expect. On some platforms, char is unsigned. On those platforms you may be comparing something like 255 vs -1 for an eof. Which means you will never detect the end of file and exit the loop.

@Someprogrammerdude how then do i do the actual character comparison between the characters i'm reading from the file and the characters in the word actual_word

@AviBerger is there a better way to handle this comparison?
I'm on Ubuntu

@Somto -- The comment section is for comments on the code, and not for answers.  I pointed out the one flaw in your code that can cause other issues.

@Somto Oh that will work fine, because when getchar succeeds the variable character will contain a plain old character (though it only uses 8 bits of the 32 available for the int), which can be compared to any other character. Remember, char values will get promoted to int in just about all cases you use a char. And that included a comparison like actual_word[word_counter] == character.

The comparison to EOF is the issue with the infinite loop. character must be of type int. The comparison in the if is OK. There are other issues in the code outside of this specific question.

Even on platforms on which char is signed, converting the int return value to a char and then comparing it with EOF can be a problem, because you would not be able to distinguish the character code 255 from the macro constant EOF (assuming that EOF is defined as -1).

It's a frequent mistake to think that a character must be a char, or a number must be an int.

@Someprogrammerdude: if character is defined as an int, the test if (actual_word[word_counter] == character) { word_counter ++;} actually does pose a potential problem if char is a signed type because the byte read from the stream is returned as the value of an unsigned char and the bytes in the array are char values.  If the array were to contain non ASCII bytes such as ç and the same character was read from the stream, they would not match.  One must indeed write if (actual_word[word_counter] == (char)character) { word_counter ++;}

Surely we must have a dupe for the "getchar doesn't work with char" FAQ? Anyone?

There are multiple issues in the code:

instead of getchar(), you should use getc(fp) or fgetc(fp) to read from the FILE * returned by fopen.

The variable character must have type int to allow reliable test for character == EOF.  If char is unsigned by default on your platform, this test is always false, hence the while loop never stops.

the message printf("Memory allocation failed") is incorrect: this might not be the reason for fopen to fail opening the source file.

char actual_word[10] = "sylvestric"; is incorrect: there is no room for the null terminator.  It is more idiomatic to write char actual_word[] = "sylvestric";.  Note however that actual_word is not used as a C string, so this does not cause a problem with the current implementation.

variable line_number is not initialized.

simply resetting word_counter to 0 on a mismatch is not sufficient for some specific cases.  For example if the file contains sylvesylvestric, the word sylvestric would not match because the second s will never be matched.

free(file_content) is incorrect: you should just close the file with fclose(file_content)


Here is a modified version:
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
    char filename[] = "fwif.txt";
    char word[] = "sylvestric";
    int word_size = strlen(word);
    int pos = 0;
    int line_number = 1;
    int status = 1;
    FILE *fp;
    int c;

    if ((fp = fopen(filename, "r")) == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Cannot open file %s: %s\n", filename, strerror(errno));
        return 1;
    }

    printf("Reading file for word '%s'...\n", word);
    while ((c = getc(fp)) != EOF) {
        if (c == '\n') {
            line_number++;
            pos = 0;
        } else
        if (word[pos] == (char)c) {
            pos++;
            if (pos == word_size) {
                printf("Word found on line: %d\n", line_number);
                status = 0;
                break;
            }
        } else {
            /* find the longest matching prefix followed by the current character */
            int pos0 = pos;
            while (pos > 0) {
                pos--;
                if (!memcmp(word, word + pos0 - pos, pos) && word[pos] == (char)c) {
                    pos++;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    fclose(fp);
    return status;
}


There is no need for a null character in actual_word; it is not used as a C string (nothing in the code relies on a null character to mark the end of the character sequence).

Thank you very much for the observations @chqrlie

definitely @PaulLynch
i've solved it already. My program words as intended

@Somto: does your updated program detect the word with an input of sylvesylvestric ?

Yes @chqrlie


@Somto: I'm afraid the program in your answer does not find sylvestric in a file that contains just sylvesylvestric...

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    FILE *file_content;  

    file_content = fopen("fwif.txt", "r");
    printf("%p \n", file_content);

    if (file_content == NULL) {
        printf("Could not read file");
        return 1;
    }  

    char actual_word[10] = "sylvestric";
    int word_counter = 0;
    int character;
    int line_number = 1;
    int word_size = 10;

    printf("Reading file for word....\n");
    while(( character = fgetc(file_content)) != EOF) {
        if (character == '\n') {
            line_number ++;
       } else {
            if (actual_word[word_counter] == character) {
                word_counter ++;
            } else {
                word_counter = 0;
            }
       }
        if (word_counter == word_size) {
            printf("Word found on line: %d\n", line_number);
            return 0;   
       }    
    }
    fclose(file_content);
    return 0;
}

This is my new code snippet that works. To read the characters i needed to use fgetc
